Should I use **array or (*array)[] for a 2D integer array?
I am writing a function which requires me to pass a 2D array of integers as a parameter with a variable amount of rows but fixed number of columns.
I was initially planning to use:
void function(int (*array)[cols]) {...}

to pass a pointer to an array of integers, which would allow me to use malloc() to allocate memory for each row depending on the amount of rows needed. However, the question comes with regard to the columns.
When allocating memory for the rows, will the appropriate memory for my specified size of columns (given by cols) be taken into account by the compiler to allocate sufficient space for all the row columns and therefore take advantage of contiguous memory?
If not, that means that I will have to allocate memory for each column of each row separately, in the case of which, wouldn't it be better to just simply use (*array)[] with no cols variable, or even better the double-pointer **array?
Would there be any differences in the functionality or efficiency of these methods?
Many thanks in advance!

The "simple" and naive way to handle it is through pointers to pointers, and together with dynamic allocation create a jagged array. If the size is known, especially at compile-time, use an array of arrays (i.e. a "2D" array) instead. This works even with variable-length arrays which have been a part of C for well over 20 years, even though one major compiler (cough MSVC cough) still doesn't implement it (IIRC).

Now, if the size is know, either at compile time, or you can use variable-length arrays, you can use it in a function passing a pointer to an array (e.g. int (*array)[cols]): Like void function(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*array)[cols]) { ... }. Then you can just create a normal array of arrays, int array[rows][cols]; and call the function passing the array as any other array: function(rows, cols, array)

Note the the 2 approaches: the genuine 2d array ( int (*array)[cols] ) with a single allocation and the imitation/simulated 2d array ( int **array ) with either 2 or rows + 1 allocations are NOT mix and match. Your code needs to be consistently written for one or the other. The first uses one contiguous memory block , the second uses more. The second also takes a performance hit due to extra pointer memory fetches. A third alternative is to use a 1d array instead and do the stride calculations yourself.


**array - pointer to pointer

Pros:

flexibility
rows can have different sizes

Cons:

complicated allocation
many levels of indirection
not cache-friendly


(*array)[cols] - pointer to array

Pros:

simple allocation
one level of indirection
more cache friendly

Cons:

more difficult syntax
VLAs not supported by many compilers


"simple allocation" -> "single allocation / single free". The levels of indirection, while I get your point, are entirely equivalent as a consequence of §6.3.2.1(p3)  Lvalues, arrays, and function designators

@DavidC.Rankin: I believe you are correct that from a "language-lawyer" perspective, the number of levels of indirection are identical in both cases. However, from the perspective of a software engineer who looks at the assembly instructions that are emitted by the compiler, I believe this answer is accurate in its claim that the number of levels of indirection are different in both cases.

@AndreasWenzel I can see your point as well as the point in the answer. There is the pointer-two-step needed when allocating a collection of pointers and then allocating storage for values. This complexity may make it appear the pointer-to-pointer involves additional indirection, but in fact there are only 2-levels of indirection in either case. The only difference being the type that results from the 1st dereference (one being a pointer-to-type, the other being being a pointer-to-array. (and the resulting difference in pointer arithmetic (sizeof(a_pointer) and sizeof(array[cols]))

@DavidC.Rankin it is not as pointer to array references contiguous memory area. When you have pointer to pointer reference to the row has to be read in addition as it can be anywhere in the memory.

That is a true statement. However, if you approach the problem by allocating your collection of pointers as a block and then reallocating when you need more, your pointers will be sequential in memory as well. Recall the pointer-two-step. You first allocate some number of pointers for your collection. Second you allocate storage for some number of values, copy your values to that new block and then assign the starting address of that block to the next allocated pointer in your collection.  That's the only reason you can index the collection using syntax similar to a 2D array.

You repeat until you run out of available pointers and then realloc() more pointers and .keep-on-trucking.... What you want to use depends on your data. If you have a cols number of values for each row, then the pointer-to-array is hard to beat. Single allocation / single free. If you have longer strings differing by lengths greater than sizeof a-pointer or so, then the 2-step offers the ability to size your storage to the exact number of bytes you are dealing with -- but does require a bit of accounting of you to keep track of your allocations and free each when no longer needed.

If I understand you, you want to pass a 2D array to a function, but you only know number of columns at compile time.
C doesn't exactly support that, unless you're willing to switch rows and columns. Then you can declare an array like this:
    int test_a[][cols] = {
        { 1,  2,  3,  4,  5},
        {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
        {21, 22, 23, 24, 25},
        // Add as many as you want...
    };

You can use the same declaration for the function:
void f(int a[][cols]) {
    printf("%d\n", a[2][2]);
}

You can declare a pointer to that array:
    int (* test_pa)[][cols] = &test_a;

It has to be dereferenced, so doesn't act like the array declaration:
    (*test_pa)[2][2] = 223;
    f(*test_pa);

You can allocate the memory this way:
    int (* test_pa)[][cols] = calloc(rows * cols, sizeof(int));
    ...
    free(test_pa);

If I didn't understand correctly, let me know.

rows , columns is the normal convention I am familiar with. Columns known at compile time is fine in C as shown in your code sample. The case where rows were known at compile time and not cols is where one could not do it unless you swapped rows for cols.

I used something like this in college for creating a 2D array in C.
int *parr,m,n;
parr=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
for(i=0;i<m;i++){
    parr[i]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
}

This will help you create a 2D array.
You can read and push elements into the array using your regular method of inserting elements into array but with the use of pointers.
for(i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        scanf("%d",(*(parr+i)+j));
    }
}


Similarly, you can print elements from the 2D array using this.
for(i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        printf("%d ",(parr)[i][j]);
    }
}

